# Net Core Framework Versions on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core

Is it possible that on an IIS web server you have two applications running. One running .NET Core 2.0 and the other 2.1?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did and I got errors, and was wondering if it's because of that. I'm still a beginner on .net

Comment: [Why “is it possible?” is a poor question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core is flexible regarding different versions running on the same web server.

Publishing an application as *self-contained*, will allow you to run as many different versions as you would like on the same web server. See [.NET Core application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/).

Only if you are publishing as *framework-dependent* would you need that specific .NET Core runtime installed on the web server. And even then you can publish applications with different versions, as long as the runtime is installed.

Different from .NET Framework, you will see that your Application Pool will have "No Managed Code" for the .NET CLR Version.

If the link above does not help resolve your issue, please provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful to know, regarding the .net core runtime

Answer (score 0):

I can answer you clearly that Yes. IIS can host multiple different versions of .net core applications.

For different versions of .net core applications, you only need to install the correct version of SDK, Runtime and Hosting Bundle on your machine. Whatever 2.0 and 2.1, or even 2.1, 3.1 and 5.0, both can run in IIS.

This is .net core 5.0 application. I use server variable to reflect current version.

```
IServerVariablesFeature serverVars = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
string iis_version = serverVars["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```

[image]

This is index page of an empty .net core 2.1 application.

[image]

Both these applications run on my local IIS.
If you want to deploy different core applications on IIS, only one thing you need to pay attention to. Do not deploy them in same application pool.

Comment: If the issue has been solved, please mark it so that it can help others with similar issue.