# .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Core 5.0 Web-Apps on Same Server

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0, .net-core-2.1, multiple-versions

We currently have a production server running multiple .NET Core 2.1 websites and we need to deploy a website running .NET Core 5.0 on that same server.

I know I need to install dotnet-hosting-5.0.7-win.exe to be able to host the new site. Will installing that version of dotnet-hosting have any negative effects on the 2.1 sites?

I just want to make sure that running both versions is possible. Thank you.

Comment: **Found my answer** here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743314/2639711](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743314/2639711)

Comment: Yes, you can. No issue with your previous website.